# Save a model instance in afterSave(), won't it run recursive?

Tags: php, recursion, yii, after-save

I need to sum count some child model data and store it in the parent model instance attribute. But for saving the attribute value I need to call `$this->save()` or `$this->saveAttributes(array('<attr name>'));`
Won't it run `save()` procedure recursively forever and, if not, why not?
Inside of *Event* model:

```
protected function afterSave() 
{
    parent::afterSave();
    $contents = EventContent::model()->findAllByAttributes(array('eventId'=>$this->id));
    if ($contents) 
    {   
        $sum=0;
        foreach($contents as $content)              
            $sum += $content->cost;  

        $this->totalSum = $sum;
        $this->save(); 
        // or $this->saveAttributes(array('totalSum'));
    }

}
```

### Update 1

As suggested by Jon, I might do it in this way:

```
protected function save() 
{    
    $contents = EventContent::model()->findAllByAttributes(array('eventId'=>$this->id));
    if ($contents) 
    {   
        $sum=0;
        foreach($contents as $content)              
            $sum += $content->cost;  

        $this->totalSum = $sum; // no need to run $this->save() here            
    } 
    parent::save(); 
}
```

### Update 2

I've updated my question to show the models' relevant code. I only accumulate sum total from child model into parent attribute. 
As asked by **lin** i share the models. The main thing here is their relation: 
*Event* (parent model) and *EventContent* (child model) are bound with this relation:

```
Class EventContent extends CActiveRecord {
  ...
  public function relations()
  {
     return array(
        'event'=>array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Event', 'eventId'),
     );
  }
}
```

Comment: You would do this inside `save` directly, not inside `afterSave`.

Comment: @Jon, do you mean i need to redefine/upgrade model's `save()` function?

Comment: Post your GII generated and all related PHP-Models please. Calling `parent::save();` sounds totally wrong to me -> due to Yii MVC pattern and OOP.

Comment: @lin: Calling `parent::save()` is *totally right* and has absolutely nothing to do with MVC.

Comment: @IgorSavinkin: Yeah. The full code might be relevant, but the general idea is just fine. It's what you are *supposed* to do. But, don't forget: a) to propagate the return value and b) Yii has calculated columns, which might be relevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your implementation of `afterSave()` is wrong and will result in endless method calls of `save()` and `afterSave()` until PHP reaches its script execution time limit.

You have two options:

1. Implement your code as suggested by Jon (your Update 1)
2. Stay with `afterSave()` and use `saveAttributes()` inside to save the model. `saveAttributes()` will not call `beforeSave()` and `afterSave()` as described in the official  [API-docs](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord#saveAttributes-detail)

In my opinion the best approach is to move your code to `save()` as Jon already suggested.

Comment: thank you. Would you point to some docs related to your main argument and `saveAttributes()` will not call `beforeSave()` and `afterSave()`?

Comment: I included a link to the API-docs where you can find the described behavior of `saveAttributes()`